# Can I DIY wire a 3.5mm 1-Female jack to 2-Females jacks?

Tags: audio, wiring

Not sure how to keep flow in a single direction. I know these cables exist and can be easily bought but I was just wondering how it was wired. [image: splitter jack]

Comment: There is nothing in these adapters that restricts signal flow to one direction only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "keeping the flow in one direction".  You just hook everything up in parallel -- ground to ground, ring to ring, tip to tip.  If you get some cable with the right number of conductors and female contacts to match, just hook up like to like and you should be OK.

Comment: A corollary to this is that there are no input and output connectors, you can use any of them as the input and the signal will appear on both of the others. Audio (which these connectors are typically used for) is sufficiently low-frequency that the different lengths don't matter. Not really important, but a bit of a fun fact!

Comment: @Hearth Thanks for the explanation, I have two inputs going to a single output and thought I would need to separate them somehow. I guess it's just up to the output / input config and keeping one input off while the other is off.

Comment: @mac_33 While you'll probably be fine, there's a chance your audio equipment might not like having signals fed into its output. I wouldn't recommend doing that sort of thing without some kind of switch.

Comment: If you have two inputs that you want to feed to one output then you need a mixer.  That's way more than just a hunk of wire and some connectors.

Comment: You have presented us with an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), and we didn't realize it in time.  I **strongly suggest** that you start a new question titled "How do I feed two audio outputs into one input?"  Expect that it may get bumped to an audio stackexchange, if there is such a think.

Comment: Thanks, for the extra info. I guess this could even be divided into three different questions (sorry). However, I'm thinking that as long as both inputs aren't "on" at the same time (which they won't be) I should be ok.